# NoReverseMatch at /polls/ Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

NoReverseMatch at /polls/

Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P[0-9]+)/vote/$']

index.html:

```
    {% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <!-- # the 'name' value as called by the  url  template tag -->
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
<!-- or:
    <li><a href=" url 'detail' question.id "> question.question_text </a></li>
    How does one make it so that Django knows which app view to create for a url when using the  url  template tag?
    So we use polls:detail
 -->
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
    </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG3kO.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSjRp.png)

Below it's console error.
Other relative questions in stackoverflow have answer like:
not question_id! It's question.id!

**error at line 123**
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P[0-9]+)/vote/$']:

```
113         {% endfor %}
114         </ul>
115         {% else %}
116             <p>No polls are available.</p>
117         {% endif %}
118     
119         <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
120     
121         {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
122     
123         <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
124         {% csrf_token %}
125         {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
126             <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
127             <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
128         {% endfor %}
129         <input type="submit" value="Vote">
130         </form>
131         </content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't got a variable called `question` at that point of the template. It only exists within your for loop, but the error is happening in the form tag which is after the end of that loop.

The `url` tag is the only one that will actually show an error, because it needs to use the value of `question.id` to create a URL; but in fact all the other uses of the variable, such as `question.question_text`, would also display as blank.

I don't quite know why you've structured your template like this, but I suspect everything from the `h1` onwards should be much higher, before the `endfor` tag.

Comment: how I can declare this question variable

Comment: I just told you, it's defined inside the for loop. So move all the code that uses it inside the loop.

Comment: it works I need to just isolate form tag to details.html

Answer (score 2):

Change ListView
`class DetailView(generic.ListView):`
to
`class DetailView(generic.DetailView):`

this may work

Answer (score 1):

error

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model= Questions
    template_name ="polls/detail.html"
    
class ResultView(generic.DetailView):
    model= Questions
    template_name ="polls/results.html"
```

solution:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model= Questions
    context_object_name = "question" 
    template_name ="polls/detail.html"
    
class ResultView(generic.DetailView):
    model= Questions
    context_object_name = "question"
    template_name ="polls/results.html"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Replying late,
but found it to be a comman typo while working out the Django docs. I am 99% sure that you named your model Questions in place of Question as django detail_view reads model name in lowercase, your template in causing reverse look up error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by adding the `form` tag in the `index.html` and not in the `detail.html`.

Just change the `html` content of the `form` to the `detail.html` template.